How do I scarify Ginkgo biloba seeds?
I have some Ginkgo biloba seeds that I want to germinate. The hard shell of the seeds need to be scarified before sowing, but how exactly should the seeds be scarified in terms of the size and position of the scars? Here's my haphazard attempt using scissors, resulting holes and cracks at different places:

Are the holes or cracks in the correct place on the seed? Are they of the correct size?

Where did you get the idea there's a science to it? Won't any crack let the seed absorb water to germinate?

@YosefBaskin I don't know. I am ignorant because this is my first time doing scarification, and I had no one else to ask about it.
